# Not able to style the ui-sref-active when its a parent of ui-sref

Tags: css, angularjs, angular-ui-router, less, ui-sref

I have been working on a simle angular navigation app.
I have gone through the ui-sref-active and ui-sref concepts. According to my understanding the ui-sref-active can be styled if ui-sref assigned to a element has ui-sref-active assigned to its parent element. I have tried a plunker here :
http://plnkr.co/edit/EhOxCw8EeQhS5uTCQBR0?p=preview

Referring to the above link, I want to achieve the following :

1. When i hover,focus or click on any of those tabs(li tag / parent tag). The background color of the tab, the icon and text color should change. When hovered or focused the changes are working fine. But when i select the tab, the changes are not reflected (I want to highlight the active tab with a change in background color and styling the icon and text). How shall i make this work.
2. I want a less code instead of css. This is the code i could come up with.It works for hover and focus. Does not work for the selected tab or active tab that is selected. Please help

   li {

   ```
    padding: 28px 5px 8px 0px;
    background: yellow
    .fa {
     font-size: 35px;
     color: blue
     }
     p {
         font-size: 18px;
        color: blue
     }
     a {
         text-decoration: none;
    }
     &:hover,
     &:focus,
     &:active {
          background-color: green;
         .fa {
             color: #fff;
         }
         p {
              color: #fff;
         }
         a {
             text-decoration: none;
         }
     }
   ```

   }

Comment: ui-sref-active adds a class if state it's selected, in your css you are referencing your parent '&:active' this is not the css selector you need it should be &.active

Comment: @Alberto That worked .Thanks a lot. Wasted lot of time on this !